# Flyway add ";" in my script

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, flyway

I have a weird issue with flyway upgrade. I have a upgrade script like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBO.initData()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    CALL DBO.myProc(1);
    CALL DBO.myProc(2);
    CALL DBO.myProc(3);
    CALL DBO.myProc(4);
    CALL DBO.myProc(5);
    CALL DBO.myProc(6);
    ......
    CALL DBO.myProc(31);
END;
```

when I run it in Data Studio, everything is fine. But if i put it in flyway upgrade. It returns an syntax error. After some investigating, i found that flyway add a ";" in my last statement and make it like`CALL DBO.myProc(3;2);`

For now i have to make two stored procedures to make it work:

init1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBO.initData()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    CALL DBO.myProc(1);
    CALL DBO.myProc(2);
    CALL DBO.myProc(3);
    CALL DBO.myProc(4);
    CALL DBO.myProc(5);
    CALL DBO.myProc(6);
    ......
    CALL DBO.myProc(31);
END;
```

init2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBO.initData2()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    CALL DBO.myProc(32);
END;
```

I am wondering if anyone knows what is wrong here?

Reproduce script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBO.wp_InitDataProc(
    v_Name VARGRAPHIC(255)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    /*do nothing*/
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBO.wp_InitData()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    CALL DBO.wp_InitDataProc(N'1');
    CALL DBO.wp_InitDataProc(N'1');
    CALL DBO.wp_InitDataProc(N'2');
END;
CALL DBO.wp_InitData();
DROP PROCEDURE DBO.wp_InitData;
DROP PROCEDURE DBO.wp_InitDataProc;
```

Comment: Please file an issue in the Flyway issue tracker with a minimal script to reproduce this.

Comment: @AxelFontaine i am not sure how to file an issue for you...But I have created a simple script which can reproduce the error (see my updates).

Comment: @AxelFontaine here is the error i get: `Migration V2_6__flyway.sql failed
---------------------------------
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : -104
Message    : DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=;;taProc(N'2');
 

END;:, DRIVER=4.17.29
Location   : ***/db/scripts/upgrade/V2_6__flyway.sql (C:\...\test.jar!\*\db\scripts\upgrade\V2_6__flyway.sql)
Line       : 11`